Hearing notes that are not there?
I am working with my teacher on recognizing notes played harmonically. She plays two notes together and I need to sing them back to her. The problem is I sometimes hear notes she is not playing, and they sound louder than the notes she is playing.
For example - she will play F4 and C5 and I will hear a very loud A4 and my mind will get stuck on it and make it impossible to hear the other notes.
Does anyone else have this problem? What are some effective exercises to get over it?

I have this problem. I think it’s common to hear the other notes but it seems like most people with trained ears can tell which notes are actually being played versus phantom notes. I have not developed that skill.

I don't hear most of these tones, but from physics, we know that 2 simultaneous notes actually have 4 notes - the principals, a frequency subtraction and a frequency addition note. That means you should hear something like an additional a5 and f3

Does this happen with specific intervals or all intervals?

@Aaron Any 2 (compatible - sound and light aren't) waves in superposition may be equivalently represented by summation and subtraction waves - if you're familiar with e^ift it's not a hard proof.

@user121330 My question was for the OP.

@Aaron We noticed it with perfect fifth, where I am adding a major third above the lower note.

Do you know if you're hearing the third in the same octave (i.e., between the root and fifth) or an octave higher?

@Aaron She says it’s between the root and fifth. She says my mind is “completing” the sound of a major chord.

If you hear 2 notes an octave apart, do you hear any other, unplayed notes? I did find I heard a phantom G once while ensuring only C's (on several octaves) were playing.

Practise listening to the two notes played in quick succession for a while, with no pedalling. Then add pedal, preferably sostenuto, then get back to simultaneous. (Assuming teacher uses piano).

@Dekkadeci I hear a major third above the bottom note

Thanks @Tim I will try!

If you hear 3 notes forming a minor chord (e.g. F4, Ab4, C5), do you hear any other, unplayed notes?

@Dekkadeci I have trouble separating three notes played together. When I tried your suggestion I mostly heard C4 and F4. Go figure.

@HNHN do you hear more than one pitch when she plays a single note?  If so, you're perhaps better than the average listener (or your ear is) at analyzing a musical tone into its component harmonics -- or maybe the piano has some particularly prominent harmonics, perhaps only in its F4 or A5.   Try different pianos (especially longer or shorter ones, both grands and uprights) and other instruments to see whether the phenomenon presents itself differently.

@phoog That’s a good test! Will try

What comes to my mind is summation tone, which is a type of combination tone.
When two notes are played, combination tones occur at the frequencies equal to difference of the two tones, and sum of the two tones. For two notes at a fifth ratio (3:2), the differential tone occurs primarily at an octave below the lower tone (1:2). The summation tone is primarily an octave + a (just) major third above the lower tone (5:2).
There is a separate question, why do you hear these tones? In typical situations, the combination tones are not heard. I even found in HANDBOOK FOR ACOUSTIC ECOLOGY by Barry Truax, 1999 a sentence "there is doubt that they [summation tones] occur at all".
Combination tones are attributed to some kind of non-linearities in the ear, and they are heard for rather loud sounds. If I remember correctly, Tartini discovered them when listening to the sound of the violin he was playing, thus close to his ears.
Maybe your ears have more non-linarity than typical? Or you are more sensitive to small details?
Some steps to produce combination tones artificially, in Audacity:

Generate a tone, e.g. 200 Hz at the amplitude of 0.5.
On another track, generate another tone, a fifth above, i.e. 300 Hz, at the same amplitude.
Select Tracks/Mix and Render, to sum the two sounds. At this stage you will likely hear just a perfect fifth.
From Effect select Distortion and Modulation/Distortion. Experiment with various settings. For me, with maximum distortion and "Even Harmonics" algorithm, the extra major third (+octave) was quite audible.


For what it's worth, which is probably not very much, the difference tone in equal temperament is theoretically about 6 cents lower than an octave below the lower tone, and the sum tone is about a cent flat of a just major tenth above it.  Is it possible that the 500 Hz tone is a difference tone between the second harmonic (400 Hz) of the lower tone and the third harmonic (900 Hz) of the upper?

I don’t know what having non linearity means. I do know that sounds other people consider normal volume are very painful to me.

@HNHN non-linearity means that response of a whatever system is not proportional to the input. E.g. a small laptop loudspeaker producing buzzing sound when put at maximum volume. This doesn't refer to any specific biological process. The fact you're more sensitive to loud sounds might be related, but at this point I must recommend you to visit a doctor, an audiologist, rather than searching for information in the internet. A doctor can check your ears, and give advice responsibly. For example, possibly you need to protect your hearing more than general population.

@phoog yes, of course harmonics add additional possibilities of intermodulation. Various effects may reinforce each other.

I don't understand the quoted comment about "not being heard...."  As you wrote, a simple audiogram will show the AM (amplitude modulation) at the sum and difference frequencies, so the overtone is most certainly there.  You might as well claim that the signal output from AM radio is "not really there" .     Furthermore, if the OP's teacher is using a piano or other acoustic stringed instrument, the instrument itself will generate sympathetic vibrations, so most certainly the frequencies exist.

@CarlWitthoft I presume by "audiogram" you mean frequency spectrum? No, if you sum two sine waves, there will be only two peaks in the frequency spectrum. Non-linear processing is necessary for other peaks to appear. For the same reason, a radio receiver is more than just a speaker connected to an antenna.

@user1079505  Sorry, no, I meant a direct display of amplitude  vs. time, not the FFT

@CarlWitthoft a sum of two sine waves is indeed equivalent to a product of sine/cosine waves with frequencies of half of the difference (not the difference), and average (not the sum) of the input frequencies. So these are not yet the frequencies of where the combination tones occur, and a product is not the same as a sum. Anyway, I claim that if one follows the instructions from my answer, at point 3, if sound is played at moderate volume, a typical person will hear only two tones. If this doesn't clarify, I think I don't understand your comment.
